# Capture JSON as string before it hits the action in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

Is there a way to capture the JSON as a string before it hits the action in the controller?

Could an attribute do the trick? I'm currently looking at Web API action filters as I know an event could be triggered before/after the action is called but I'm not sure how will I handle this for the data being received so that I can parse it and ensure that not script injection is included in the JSON string

Can this be done? Is this the correct way to go about it or is there a better way to handle this without the use of third-party tools,

Thanks.

Comment: by using custom Filters?

Comment: Have you tried looking into HttpContext properties? Filters also have access to HttpContext, and I'm almost sure you can access received data there. I can't guarantee now, but soon I'll do some tests

Comment: @DanielCunha, you are correct. I can but I still haven't figured out how to actually access the JSON. I can see the data being posted but it is provided as oject rather than a string. I'll update if I find out how.

Answer (score 2):

Not my work, but this very useful article by Mark Ashley Bell solved this same problem for me. You need to scroll down to where Mark talks about Model Binding.

https://markb.uk/asp-net-core-read-raw-request-body-as-string.html

(btw ActionFilters occur too late in the process, after the model binding has already occurred, so if there is any issue in de-serialising (which might be why you'd want to see the raw JSON in the first place), then you wouldn't have got this far. A colleague shared this article on that with me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Based on Mark's work (and you would need the other bits from his article too), this can be captured (here I am using OpenTelemetry to record this for instance)):

```
public class EnableRequestBodyBufferingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public EnableRequestBodyBufferingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) =>
        _next = next;

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        ActivitySource source = new($"{AppConstants.ApplicationName}.{GetType().Name}");
        using var activity = source.StartActivity($"{GetType().Name}.{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}");

        context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    
        // Read the raw body request
        var rawRequestBody = await context.Request.GetRawBodyAsync();
        activity?.AddTag("Request.RawBody", rawRequestBody.ToString());

        await _next(context);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can capture json string before the controll is hit. You need to use `ActionFilters` which are executed before the controller method is hit.